# replace object inside ng repeat

Tags: angularjs

how can i replace value inside ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in test">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="item.qty">
</div>

$scope.test = [
        {"InventoryItemID":78689,"Location":"My Location",qty:"2"},
        {"InventoryItemID":78689,"Location":"My Location",qty:"1"}
    ]
```

now i have to replace the test qty with test1 qty . how can i do that.

```
$scope.test1 = [
            {qty:"6"},
            {qty:"6"}
        ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, can you try and rephrase it?

Comment: Would they have the same index?

Comment: @Jordumus : i have to replace $scope.test qty value with $scope.test1 qty

Comment: I am trying to guess your flow.  in controller, first you get $scope.test = [{}].  You will see values on view.  Then you get $scope.test1.  Now If you just need to override all values of test qty with **corresponding** test1 qty, then you can iterate and replace test[i].qty = test1[i].qty.  Does anything stop you from that.  Even if you don't want to replace it, you can have two fields - initialqty and actualqty.  let initialqty =actualqty.  In view {{item.actualqty}}, now when you get test1, update test1.qty into test.actualqty.  that will be safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have one object that hold the values you need, and use `test` and `test1` as temporary values, for example:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="item.qty">
</div>

var test = [
        {"InventoryItemID":78689,"Location":"My Location",qty:"2"},
        {"InventoryItemID":78689,"Location":"My Location",qty:"1"}
    ]

var test1 = [
            {qty:"6"},
            {qty:"6"}
        ]

$scope.items = test;
```

Then, to swap it, just do:

```
$scope.items = test1;
```

That would be the "Angular way" of doing it.

---

See it live:

```js
angular.module('App', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.test = [
        {"InventoryItemID":78689,"Location":"My Location",qty:"2"},
        {"InventoryItemID":78689,"Location":"My Location",qty:"1"}
    ]

  $scope.test1 = [
            {qty:"6"},
            {qty:"6"}
        ]

  $scope.items = $scope.test;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="item.qty">
  </div>
  <br>
  <button ng-click="items = test">Use Test</button>
  <button ng-click="items = test1">Use Test1</button>
  <br><br>
  {{items}}
</div>
```

---

EDIT

I might've misread the question.

If you just want to update quantities, you can do it just like with any other JavaScript object, for example, an old-school for-loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.test.length; i++){
    $scope.test[i].qty = $scope.test1[i].qty;
}
```

Comment: what if i need only qty to replace rather than the whole object?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
$scope = this; // Ignore this line

$scope.test = [
        {"InventoryItemID":78689,"Location":"My Location",qty:"2"},
        {"InventoryItemID":78689,"Location":"My Location",qty:"1"}
    ]

$scope.test1 = [
     {qty: "6"},
     {qty: "6"}
]

$scope.test.forEach(function(value, index){
  Object.assign(value, $scope.test1[index])
})

console.log($scope.test)
```